# Ruby string to octal?

Tags: ruby

How can I convert "755" to 0755 in Ruby? I want to pass permissions to a method using a string and then convert it for chmod use.

Comment: It's not clear what you actually want.  Do you want to append zero to a string? Or what?

Comment: I want to convert a string to an octal, like the title says.

Comment: @Pavel: "755" == 0755 returns false...

Comment: No, it’s not. It’s a string. He wants to convert it to an integer in base 8. The question is perfectly clear.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This should do it:

```
"755".to_i(8)
# => 493

"755".to_i(8) == 0755
# => true
```

Comment: Fantastic, did this test in irb and got "true" -> 0755 == "755".to_i(8)

Comment: Just added that to my answer so people understand what this is for.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but you can check for input errors by passing the string and base to instantiate an Integer thus,

```
Integer("755",8)=493
Integer("855",8)
ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer(): "855"

begin
     Integer("855",8)
rescue ArgumentError, TypeError
     "Bad input"
end
```

Answer (score -4):

```
def append_zero_to_string(string)
    0.to_s + string
end
```

Comment: He expects not a string. Whereas "755" is a string, 0755 is not a string.